# Append text to column using go with pq driver

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I am trying to append text to a database column using golang and the pq driver.

The error I am getting is `panic: pq: could not determine data type of parameter $2`

```
sqlStatement := `
UPDATE sales
SET description = concat(description, $2)
WHERE id = $1;`

id:=1
desc := "appendthis"

res, err := db.Exec(sqlStatement, id, desc)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

I also tried 
`SET description = description || $2` which didn't panic, though the field did not get updated.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/281#issuecomment-307247685 ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you are binding the parameters correctly.

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks, SET description = concat(description, $2::varchar) works.